# When I tried to start MySQL in xampp. I am getting this error

Tags: mysql

Problem detected Port 3306 m use by C Program Files (x86)MySQL MySQL Server 5.0ibinimysqld MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application

or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Comment: Sounds like you already have MySQL installed, independently from XAMP.

Comment: You have 2 MySQL Servers running both of which are trying to listen on tcp port 3306. Only one server using the same port number is allowed

Comment: I would uninstall the OTHER MySQL, after you check and backup any databases that may exist on that version of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Other program is working on port 3306.
You may close this program, or change Mysql's port.
This setting can be changed in Mysql config.